# How to assign the value of an element of list as new element of buffer list in Scala?

Tags: arrays, list, scala

I'm trying to calculate sum and average of "ViewTime" per each "DayOfWeek" and also per "DayOfWeek" per "id". As an example I have tried to do that when DayOfWeek == "Monday" . I was trying to make a list of id and a list of ViewTime but I encountered with the following error. what is the best solution?

```
case class ds(DayOfWeek : String, id: String, ViewTime: Long)

val datasample = Array(ds("Monday", "h100", 20).productIterator.toList,  ds("Tuesday", "h200", 30).productIterator.toList, ds("Monday", "h400", 10).productIterator.toList, ds("Sunday", "h100", 4).productIterator.toList, ds("Tuesday", "h300", 5).productIterator.toList, ds("Sunday", "h200", 0).productIterator.toList, ds("Tuesday", "h100", 1).productIterator.toList, ds("Tuesday", "h400", 50).productIterator.toList)

var bufInt = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]
var bufString = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]

val y = datasample.length
var x = ds("Tuesday", "h200", 30).productIterator.toList

var j = 0 
var s = 0

while (j <= y-1) {
  x =  datasample(j) 
  if ( x(0) == "Monday") {
      bufInt += x(2)
      bufString += x(1)
      s += 1
}
j += 1
}
println(bufInt)
println(bufString)
```

**error** :

```
<console>:61: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: Int
                    bufInt += x(2)
                               ^
<console>:62: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
                    bufString += x(1)
                                  ^
```

Comment: `ds("Monday", "h100", 20).productIterator.toList,` Why are you doing this, only to access the elements by index later? It makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, I think I should talk about the difference between **List** and **Tuple**

**List** must hold the same type of value, while **Tuple** can contain different type of elements. For this reason,

```
ds("Tuesday", "h200", 30).productIterator.toList
```

will produce a List of

```
List(Tuesday, h200, 30)
```

the first element is **Tuesday**, the second is **h200** and the third is **30**. But what's the type of these elements? As we have known, the **List** must contain the same type of element and obviously the type of **List(Tuesday, h200, 30)** is not **String**, and is also not **Int**.

The type of **String** and **Int** are extended from type of **Any**. So we can say that **List(Tuesday, h200, 30)** holds the elements with type of **Any**

The "+=" of **bufInt** needs operator with type of **Int** while **bufString** needs **String**, which both not are **Any**. so the errors appeared.

Just modify your code like this following

```
case class ds(DayOfWeek : String, id: String, ViewTime: Long)

val datasample = Array(ds("Monday", "h100", 20),  ds("Tuesday", "h200", 30), ds("Monday", "h400", 10), ds("Sunday", "h100", 4), ds("Tuesday", "h300", 5), ds("Sunday", "h200", 0), ds("Tuesday", "h100", 1), ds("Tuesday", "h400", 50))

var bufInt = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int]
var bufString = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]

val y = datasample.length
var x = ds("Tuesday", "h200", 30)

var j = 0
var s = 0

while (j <= y-1) {
  x = datasample(j)
  if ( x.DayOfWeek == "Monday") {
    bufInt += x.id.toInt
    bufString += x.id
    s += 1
  }
  j += 1
}
println(bufInt)
println(bufString)
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

First, a slightly less warped way of doing what you want:

```
case class ds(DayOfWeek : String, id: String, ViewTime: Long)

val datasample = Array(ds("Monday", "h100", 20),
                       ds("Tuesday", "h200", 30),
                       ds("Monday", "h400", 10),
                       ds("Sunday", "h100", 4),
                       ds("Tuesday", "h300", 5),
                       ds("Sunday", "h200", 0),
                       ds("Tuesday", "h100", 1),
                       ds("Tuesday", "h400", 50)) 

// changed Int to Long here to match the case class

val bufInt = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Long]
val bufString = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]

for (sample <- datasample
     if  sample.DayOfWeek == "Monday") {
       bufInt += sample.ViewTime
       bufString += sample.id
}
println(bufInt)                                   //> ListBuffer(20, 10)
println(bufString)                                //> ListBuffer(h100, h400)
```

and then the more idiomatic way:

```
datasample.collect{case ds(day, id, _) if day == "Monday" => id}
//> res0: Array[String] = Array(h100, h400)
datasample.collect{case ds(day, _, time) if day == "Monday" => time}
//> res1: Array[Long] = Array(20, 10)
```

or if you prefer `for` comprehensions:

```
for (sample <- datasample
     if  sample.DayOfWeek == "Monday") yield sample.ViewTime
                                              //> res2: Array[Long] = Array(20, 10)

for (sample <- datasample
     if  sample.DayOfWeek == "Monday") yield sample.id
                                              //> res3: Array[String] = Array(h100, h400)
```

The whole point of case classes etc is to provide a convenient way of collecting things together into one structure. Unpacking them with `productIterator` into a single list is just bizarre, and I've no idea why you start off down that route.